# Android - How to get all the childrens under the custom listview even if we perform scrolling

Tags: java, android

I have a custom listview adapter with a checkbox,imageview, textview. and i also have a button and a checkbox(for select all) in my main layout(not in listview).

What here i want is to check all these listview checkboxes at once when i check my main layout's checkbox.And I want to get that related textview id as dynamically.

i tried few techniques using getChaildAT(i).but it's not working with my code.with this i'm able to check/uncheck only particular visible group of checkboxes.While scroll down to list it get failed.

My aim is to check/uncheck all the checkboxes even with scroll and get the related id's.So Pls provide any other way to get all the children count in that custom list view.

In main activity I've custom adapter code like this

```
filterlist.setAdapter(new CustomAdptr(this));
class CustomAdptr extends ArrayAdapter {
        Activity context;
        String[] eventtypename;
        CustomAdptr(Activity context) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, filterListdata);
            rowView.clear();
            this.context = context;
        }
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View viewrow = convertView;
            if (viewrow == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                viewrow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filterlistrow, null);
            }
            ImageView iw = (ImageView)viewrow.findViewById(R.id.img);
            try {
                String image = filterListdata.get(position).getFilterImg();
                byte[] imbbyte = com.cincinnati.parks.Base64.decode(image);;
                Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imbbyte,0,imbbyte.length);
                iw.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            TextView tv = (TextView)viewrow.findViewById(R.id.title);
            tv.setText(filterListdata.get(position).getFilterImageName());
            final CheckBox chkbx = (CheckBox)viewrow.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            chkbx.setChecked(true);
            TextView selectedid = (TextView)viewrow.findViewById(R.id.rid);
            selectedid.setText(String.valueOf(filterListdata.get(position).getFilterImgId()));
            rowView.add(viewrow);
            viewrow.setClickable(true);
            viewrow.setFocusable(true);
            checkboxImagelist.clear();
            for(int i=0;i<filterListdata.size();i++) {
                checkboxImagelist.add(filterListdata.get(i).getFilterImgId());
            }
            chkbx.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (chkbx.isChecked()) {
                        FilterImageId.clear();
                        checkboxImagelistall.clear();
                        topOkbuttongray.setVisibility(4);
                        topOkbutton.setVisibility(0);
                        rb = (CheckBox) v;                           
                        FilterImageId.add(filterListdata.get(position).getFilterImgId());
                        checkboxImagelist.addAll(FilterImageId);
                        checkboxImagelistall.addAll(FilterImageId);
                    }else {
                        FilterImageId.clear();
                        FilterImageId.add(filterListdata.get(position).getFilterImgId());
                        checkboxImagelistall.remove(FilterImageId);
                        checkboxImagelist.removeAll(FilterImageId);
                        if((checkboxImagelist.size()) == 0){
                            topOkbuttongray.setVisibility(0);
                            topOkbutton.setVisibility(4);
                        }
                        if (filterListdata.size() != checkboxImagelist.size()) all.setChecked(false);
                    }
                    if (filterListdata.size() == heckboxImagelist.size()) all.setChecked(true); 
                }
            });
            return (viewrow);
        }
    }
```

The below code is for check all button

```
OnClickListener radio_listener = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

int Id;
System.out.println("enter set all button");
rb = (CheckBox) v;
if(rb.isChecked()) {
System.out.println("enter set all button rb.isChecked()");
topOkbutton.setVisibility(0);
topOkbuttongray.setVisibility(4);
checkboxImagelistall.clear();
checkboxImagelist.clear();
//markAll(true); 
for(int i=0;i<filterListdata.size();i++) {
Id = filterListdata.get(i).getFilterImgId();
checkboxImagelistall.add(Id);
checkboxImagelist.add(Id);
}
System.out.println("In enable condition filterlist.getChildCount()============="+filterlist.getChildCount());
System.out.println("In enable condition filterlist.getAdapter().getCount()============="+filterlist.getAdapter().getCount());
/*for(int i=0; i < filterlist.getAdapter().getCount(); i++){*/
for(int i=0; i < filterlist.getChildCount(); i++){
LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout)filterlist.getChildAt(i);
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
//CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)filterlist.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
cb.setChecked(true);
TextView tv = (TextView)filterlist.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.rid);
rowIdstr.add(tv.getText().toString());
}
}else {
System.out.println("enter set all button rb.isChecked() Not");
all.setChecked(false);
rb.setChecked(false);
topOkbutton.setVisibility(4);
topOkbuttongray.setVisibility(0);
System.out.println("In disable condition filterlist.getChildCount()============="+filterlist.getChildCount());
System.out.println("In disable condition filterlist.getAdapter().getCount()============="+filterlist.getAdapter().getCount());
//markAll(false); 
for(int i=0; i < filterlist.getChildCount(); i++){
//CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)filterlist.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout)filterlist.getChildAt(i);
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
cb.setChecked(false);
rowIdstr.clear();
checkboxImagelistall.clear();
}
}
}
};
all.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);
```

And I used below .xml files for custom listing
for check all button in main layout I used this

```
<CheckBox  android:id="@+id/radioselectall" 
   android:layout_width="30dp"  android:layout_height="20dp" 
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:checked="true" />
```

And the listview is

```
<ListView 
android:id="@+id/listm" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And another .xml file is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="left"
>
    <CheckBox
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:checked="true"/>
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"/>
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    />
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rid"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16sp" 
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that except storing the states in data underlying your adapter items, because there is actually finite number of recyclable items in a list view, it's significantly smaller than the possible number of data items.

So, my suggestion is either store an *ArrayList* of *Booleans* corresponding to the items in your filterListdata or add the booleans to the items stored in filterListdata. And then in *getView()* set checked state of the checkbox according to the boolean checked flag of the item.
This way, when you need to check all checkboxes in the *ListView*, you can run through all the items and set all checked flags to true, then call *notifyDataSetChanged()* to update visible items. And, of course, you'll have to set the checked flag in your *OnClickListener* for check box.

I'm not sure about what you mean by getting item ids though. Again, you can traverse your data array and for each item know whether it's checked or not.

Couple more comments:

- Consider using *OnCheckedChangeListener* and the corresponding setter instead of *OnClickListener* for checkbox
- Consider using only one listener instance for all checkboxes. Now you're creating a new one for each item. If the user ever wants to scroll your list fast, the app will have to create a massive load of useless new objects in the process, which will choke the GC (it'll have to constantly perform garbage collection) and the whole experience will be very chunky.
- Use [ViewHolder](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7767) pattern to avoid creating bitmaps each time a new item needs to be displayed. This, too, can be a dramatic performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

After marking all checkboxes as true/false, call `invalidate();` on list. This will refresh all the elements (visible or non-visible) in the list with latest properties set.

Try out.